# Displaying Error Message from C# AfterInstall Event

Tags: c#, windows, installation

Can someone please tell me how to display error message in C# during execution of AfterInstallEvent?

My project uses the Microsoft set-up and deployment project and then I have created a class that is called when the AfterInstall event is fired.

MessageBox.Show(); doesn't work..."The name 'MessageBox' does not appear in the current context".

If it was that simple, I wouldn't be asking!?

Answer (score 2):

The real solution is to use scope. Something like this:
global::System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex,"Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This is very old but I'll answer anyway:

**It's just a missing reference.**

Add a reference to **System.Windows.Forms** to the project containing the class.
Also add **"using System.Windows.Forms;"** to the top of your class file.

As far as I know there shouldn't be any issues with displaying message boxes from a custom install action.